# Understanding MVC pattern of PDFKit Apple framework for a Presentation

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-high-sierra, pspdfkit

I want to represent, for a presentation, the PDFKit framework of Apple as an MVC pattern, should i assume there is a PDFViewController for the PDFView, PDFDocumentController for the PDFDocument and so on, or because it's an API it's not possibile to represent it with this pattern?

The following is an image form WWDC 2017 slide about the components:

[image]

Also as stated here ( https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/migration-guides/migrating-from-apple-pdfkit/) the PDFView seems to be both a view and a controller, does this make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

Apple's `PDFView` is a view, not a view controller. It inherits from UIView. See the "Inherits From" section in the [Apple API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfview). While PSPDFKit's `PSPDFViewController` is a view controller. It inherits from UIViewController.

In the [Migrating from Apple PDFKit](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/migration-guides/migrating-from-apple-pdfkit/) article, `PSPDFViewController` is the corresponding UI component for Apple's `PDFView` in the context of [PDFXKit](https://github.com/PSPDFKit/PDFXKit), which a drop-in replacement for Apple PDFKit which uses PSPDFKit framework under the hood.

See our [Introducing PDFXKit](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2017/introducing-pdfxkit/) blog post for more details.

Comment: Yes, it looks like that because the PDFKit it's an API, it doesn't expose the application logic. Thus they obviously used a PDFViewController, PDFDocumentController, but you can't see it from the interface of the API.